# Building an OAuth provider for custom API

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

I would like to use oAuth as a system to allow developers access to my API but not require them to pass through the login information.

There does not seem to be any good how-to's or blogs on this topic. Everything I have found is based on consuming an oAuth system such as Facebook or twitter. Wondering if anyone has any links to good instructions or libraries that could get me started. If there are no examples out there perhaps someone could consider writing one, the community really needs it.

Answer (score 2):

Using OAuth to login is actually a side-effect, not the main goal of the protocol. The best place to start with providing an OAuth-protected API is the protocol specification and since this is a new service, you should take a look at OAuth 2.0 [1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-20). It is pretty much done and ready for deployment.

To implement OAuth 2.0 you will need to make a few important decisions about which features you are going to support and your scaling needs. There are also a lot of security considerations to go through. I would suggest you start with supporting the authorization code and implicit grant types.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). It should work for your needs, but I've only used it for the OpenID stuff.

Comment: thanks this is probably the best one I could find but no good tutorials or how-to's, which is more what I'm looking for.  Any links for Tutorials?